# Getting _tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "400*400"

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this Code :

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
root.title('Popup')
root.iconbitmap('D:/Test/Hulk.ico')
root.geometry("400*400")
def popup():
    response = messagebox.showinfo("Popup Test...", "Hello Stifler !")
    Label(root, text=response).pack()

Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=popup).pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. "400*400" is not a valid geometry specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
root.geometry("400x400")
```

`*` should be replaced with `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the character lowercase 'x' instead of '*' to indicate multiplication.
It will work!.